# Change table-responsive breakpoint in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have a table that takes the "table-responsive" class and works as expected when the screen shrinks to ~760px but i want the behavior in 1300px itself. Is it possible? I tried media-queries but i guess i didnt get it well. is that what I'm supposed to use ?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, [this will be fixed in Bootstrap v3.2.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/feed9aed5b471c20b02c4ca6620366cac9327db8).

Until then, you can easily add the fix manually:

```
.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```